# I can not activated Google Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets-api

I need assistance on setting up Google Sheets API. Here are the instructions I was provided:

> 1. Go to this page: https://console.cloud.google.com/
> 2. New Project
> 3. You can name the project whatever you like and set the other questions however you organization needs. We don't need specific here.
> 4. Once you have a project, open the project and click the three lines in the top left corner> API and Services > Credentials
> 5. Create Credentials > API Key > Restrict Key
> 6. Under Application Restrictions > HTTP referrers (web sites)
> 7. Under Websites Restrictions > Add an Item: enter the option that follows:  *.formstack.com/*
> 8. After you Click Done go to API Restrictions
> 9. Restrict Key > choose Google Sheets API

I followed everything but when I got to # 8. Google Sheets API is not an option and only the following "Google Cloud API" is the closest thing.

[image: this]

Comment: Hey Mark, were you able to solve your issue with my answer? Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it in case it was useful to you. Otherwise, kindly describe the issue you are having,  so we may help you. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The Google Sheets API does not appear in the "API restrictions" drop-down because you have not enabled the API for this project.

#### Enabling the Google Sheets API for your project

1. Head over to Google Developers Console.
2. Select your project in the top drop-down.
3. Head over to `Library`. Search for the `Google Sheets API` item and select it.

[image]

4. Click on `ENABLE`.

[image]

#### Result

Now, after repeating the same process you described you should be able to see the newly enabled API in the "API restrictions" drop-down. In my case, more APIs show up such as `YouTube Data API v3` or `Google Drive API` since they are enabled in my project:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me and should be marked as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same problem today. I found that it is the cache problem.
I opened the Dev console of the Chrome and then go to the `Network` tab and checked the `Disable cache` and refresh the page. Then `Google Sheets API` appear in the dropdown list!
Hope it helps to someone like me.[image]

Comment: I was having the same issue and your solution worked. Thank you.